# What is a better way to replace IDs in an array with their value counterpart?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, explode, implode

I have the following array that includes id:

```
[Key1] => 1
[Key2] => 2, 3
```

I would like to replace these ids by their respective name from this second array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 1
        [Name] => Name1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 2
        [Name] => Name2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 3
        [Name] => Name3
```

The desired output:

```
[Key1] => Name1
[Key2] => Name2, Name3
```

I have the following code which works but I know this is not the right way. If anybody could let me know what would be a better way to achieve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

What my code looks like:

```
$var1 = explode(", ", $array1["Key1"]); // No need to explode in this example but "Key1" sometimes includes more than 1 ID
$var2 = explode(", ", $array1["Key2"]);

$array1["Key1"] = $var1 ; // This row is for the new array generated from "explode" to be a sub-array
$array1["Key2"] = $var2 ; // Same

for ($i = 0; $i < 83; $i++){
    if($array1["Key1"][0] == $array2[$i]["ID"]){
        $array1["Key1"][0] = $array2[$i]["Name"];
    }
    if($array1["Key1"][1] == $array2[$i]["ID"]){
        $array1["Key1"][1] = $array2[$i]["Name"];
    }
// (etc)
    if($array1["Key2"][0] == $array2[$i]["ID"]){
        $array1["Key2"][0] = $array2[$i]["Name"];
    }
    if($array1["Key2"][1] == $array2[$i]["ID"]){
        $array1["Key2"][1] = $array2[$i]["Name"];
    }   
// (etc)

}

$var1 = implode(", ", $array1["Key1"]);
$var2 = implode(", ", $array1["Key2"]);

$array1["Key1"] = $var1 ;
$array1["Key2"] = $var2 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the `ID` and `Name` into a single-dimension and use it as search and replace parameters. We need to modify the `ID`s to search for and turn them into a pattern `/\b$v\b/` where `\b` is a word boundary, so that `1` won't replace the `1` in `164` for example:

```
$replace = array_column($array2, 'Name', 'ID');
$search  = array_map(function($v) { return "/\b$v\b/"; }, array_keys($replace));

$array1 = preg_replace($search, $replace, $array1);
```

Comment: I really like your idea AbraCadaver but I am having a small problem with it. For instance if we have '164' as an ID it will identify '1' as an ID and replace it with a name, leaving 64 at the end since 6,4 or 64 are not IDs in my list. Therefore, the ID 164 is replaced by the name corresponding to ID 1 following by the number 64 even though ID 164 exists. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Good catch.  I fixed with `preg_replace` and a pattern that looks for word boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

You need to nest some loops. Here is a [sample](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c94361af45b2634b9467a65546835685db339613) that should work:

```
//Processing Array
$arrayOne = array(
    "Key1"  =>  "1",
    "Key2"  =>  "2, 3");

//Lookup Array
$arrayTwo = array(
    array(
        "ID" => "1", 
        "Name" => "Name1"),
    array(
        "ID" => "2", 
        "Name" => "Name2"),
    array(
        "ID" => "3", 
        "Name" => "Name3"));

var_dump($arrayOne);

//Loop through all values in our original array
foreach($arrayOne as &$arrValue) {
    //Split the value in the original array into another temporary array 
    //if there are multiple values.
    $valueArray = explode(", ", $arrValue);
    $outputArray = array();
    foreach($valueArray as &$myValue) {
        //Now do a lookup to replace each value
        foreach($arrayTwo as &$lookupValue) {
            //Find a match
            if($myValue==$lookupValue["ID"]) {
                $myValue = $lookupValue["Name"];
                //We found the value we want, so let's break out of this loop
                break;
            }
        }
        //Append the value
        array_push($outputArray, $myValue);
    }
    //Convert back to string
    $arrValue= implode(", ", $outputArray);
}

var_dump($arrayOne);
```

There are improvements you could possibly make to this code if your incoming data was always sorted, but I imagine that is just the case for your sample above.

Answer (score 2):

I have an approach to do this. You can make a try if you wish see here at:- https://eval.in/839823. I am using [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to map the **key=>value** pair and then simple used [foreach](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihvdzK_bPVAhXEKo8KHUqSBA4QFgglMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fcontrol-structures.foreach.php&usg=AFQjCNF26whVK5kZ88ZdgYyCkepbXqUaPg).

```
<?php
$main = ['Key1' => 1,'Key2' => '2, 3'];

$match = [
    [
        'ID' => 1,
        'Name' => 'Name1'
    ],

    [
        'ID' => 2,
        'Name' => 'Name2'
    ],
    [
        'ID' => 3,
        'Name' => 'Name3'
    ]
 ];

$final_array=[];
$mapped = array_column($match, 'Name', 'ID');
foreach($main as $k=>$v){
   $r = explode(',',$v);
    if(count($r)>1){
       $final_array[$k] = $mapped[$r[0]]. ", ".$mapped[intval($r[1])];
    }else{
       $final_array[$k] = $mapped[$r[0]];
    }
}    
print '<pre>';
//print_r($mapped);
print_r($final_array);
print '</pre>';
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [Key1] => Name1
    [Key2] => Name2,Name3
)
```

**Edit** : As per comment of **Josh Maag**,

> My code will only work if he only has a maximum of 2 values in Key2.
>   If Key3 contains "4,5,6" this code will leave the 6 untouched.

```
<?php


 $main = ['Key1' => 1,'Key2' => '2,3','Key3' => '4,5,6'];

    $match = [
        [
            'ID' => 1,
            'Name' => 'Name1'
        ],

        [
            'ID' => 2,
            'Name' => 'Name2'
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 3,
            'Name' => 'Name3'
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 4,
            'Name' => 'Name4'
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 5,
            'Name' => 'Name5'
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 6,
            'Name' => 'Name6'
        ]
     ];

    $final_array=[];
    $mapped = array_column($match, 'Name', 'ID');
    foreach($main as $k=>$v){
       $r = explode(',',$v);
        if(count($r)>1){
           $final_array[$k] =  implode(',',array_map(function($key) use ($mapped){ return $mapped[$key]; }, array_values($r)));
        }else{
           $final_array[$k] = $mapped[$r[0]];
        }
    }    

    print '<pre>';
    print_r($mapped);
    print_r($final_array);
    print '</pre>';
    ?>
```

See demo See here https://eval.in/839939

Comment: Being Sunny, your solution will only work if he only has a maximum of 2 values in Key2. If Key3 contains "4,5,6" this code will leave the 6 untouched.

Comment: @JoshMaag please have a look on my Edit :)

Answer (score 0):

The core function that should be used for this task is `preg_replace_callback()`.  Why?  Because it is uniquely qualified to handle this operation in a single function call.  It seems a tragedy to not use php functions for their designed purpose.

Beyond `preg_replace_callback()`, only `array_column()` is needed to prepare the `$array2` data as a simple lookup array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ADMZP))

```
$array1 = ["Key1" => "1", "Key2" => "22, 4, 123"];
$array2 = [
    ["ID" => "1", "Name" => "Name1"],
    ["ID" => "22", "Name" => "Name22"],
    ["ID" => "123", "Name" => "Name123"]
];

$lookup = array_column($array2, 'Name', 'ID');
var_export(
    preg_replace_callback(
        '/\d+/',
        fn($m) => $lookup[$m[0]] ?? $m[0],
        $array1
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Key1' => 'Name1',
  'Key2' => 'Name22, 4, Name123',
)
```

There is no need to run any preparations (excluding `$lookup`) using additional loops or function calls.

This pattern will match all full `ID` numbers from each element in `$array1` and process them individual.  Each numeric match is sent to the anonymous callback function to receive its customized replacement string -- delivered by the `$lookup` data.

If the matched substring isn't found as a `ID` value in `$lookup`, no replacement will be made (the original number will be returned unchanged).