# With preg_match it's possible to have the same pattern and have different replacements?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace

I create this pattern

```
$pattern = "/<a href='(?<href>.+?)'>(?<name>.+?)<\/a>/i";
```

And i have this example,

```
$string = "<a href='https://www.php.net/'>https://www.php.net/</a> 
<a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>https://stackoverflow.com/</a> 
<a href='https://www.google.com/'>https://www.google.com/</a>";
```

Using this, i can find the matches and extract the href, and the name.

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.php.net/
            [1] => https://stackoverflow.com/
            [2] => https://www.google.com/
        )

    [href] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.php.net/
            [1] => https://stackoverflow.com/
            [2] => https://www.google.com/
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.php.net/
            [1] => https://stackoverflow.com/
            [2] => https://www.google.com/
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.php.net/
            [1] => https://stackoverflow.com/
            [2] => https://www.google.com/
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.php.net/
            [1] => https://stackoverflow.com/
            [2] => https://www.google.com/
        )

)
```

The problem is when I use the preg_replace, since the pattern is the same, it changes the same information for all the URL, and i need to change only the name and preserve the rest of the information accordingly.

Using,

```
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches))
{
    $string = preg_replace($pattern, "<a href='$1'>Name</a>", $string);

}
```

I can get the results from the groups, and preserve the first part of the href. But if i try to change the name, it's the same for all results.

If I try to use "str_replace", I can have different results as intended, but this gave me 2 problems. One is that if i try to replace the name, i also change the href, and if i have similar URL with "more slashes" it will change the match part, and leave the rest of the information.

In a database I have list of URL with a column that have names, and if the string match any row in the table I need to change the name accordingly and preserve the href.

Any help?

Thank you.

Kind regards!

Comment: Looks a bit like https://stackoverflow.com/a/52989605/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324960/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/45806855/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/45685528/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/48730001/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068407/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you retrieve rows from your database with a format such as this:

```
$rows = [
  ['href' => 'https://www.php.net/', 'name' => 'PHP.net'],
  ['href' => 'https://stackoverflow.com/', 'name' => 'Stack Overflow'],
  ['href' => 'https://www.google.com/', 'name' => 'Google']
];
```

From there, you can first create an href -> name map using a loop or [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/array_reduce):

```
$rows_by_href = array_reduce($rows, function ($rows_by_href, $row) {
  $rows_by_href[$row['href']] = $row['name'];
  return $rows_by_href;
}, []);
```

You can then use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) to replace each match with its associated name if it exists:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) use ($rows_by_href) {
  return "<a href='" . $matches['href'] . "'>" 
    . ($rows_by_href[$matches['href']] ?? $matches['name']) 
    . "</a>";
}, $string);

echo $result;
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/IY6p0**

Note that this assumes the URLs (href) within `$string` are formatted the exact same way as the ones coming from your DB. Otherwise you can `rtrim` the trailing slashes or do anything else you need beforehand.

Also note that it's usually a bad idea to parse HTML with regular expressions if you can avoid it. A DOM parser is way more appropriate, unless you have to parse a string that comes from a comment or forum post or something not in your control.

Comment: Didn't know about the preg_replace_callback. Thank you for the help.